# Google maps is showing blank after publishing

Tags: android, google-maps

I know that this question was raised several times, but I tried all WA and didn't help. My app in debug mode is working normally, but after generating signed copy google map shows blank screen with google logo.

[image]

I tried generating new API key, restricting it using SHA1 obtained from my keystorefile used in generating the signed APK, I made sure that package and SHA1 are correctly added, I repeated all these steps several times but problem still the same!
Here is my code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_maps, container, false);

    mMapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.map);
    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mMapView.onResume(); // needed to get the map to display immediately

    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        checkLocationPermission();
    }
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.

    mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override


        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            mMap = googleMap;
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
            googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);

            //Initialize Google Play Services
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    buildGoogleApiClient();
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }
            } else {
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    });


    final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService( getActivity().LOCATION_SERVICE );

    if ( !manager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) ) {
        buildAlertMessageNoGps();
    }
    return rootView;
}

private void buildAlertMessageNoGps() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setMessage("Your GPS seems to be disabled, do you want to enable it?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(@SuppressWarnings("unused") final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mMapView.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mMapView.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mMapView.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mMapView.onLowMemory();
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getContext())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}
```

And here is may manifest part:

```
   <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

and this is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Are you using ProGuard for your release build?  If so, check you have related settings for Google Maps e.g. https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/app/proguard-rules.pro

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. my API was not present in release xml file.